# Is there any way that I can direct to another page based on the email address that I provide?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            //user is logged in
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const AdminHomePage();
            }
            //user is not loggen in
            else {
              return const UserOrAdmin();
            }
          }),
```

I'm building an app that has a user page and an admin page. I wish to stay logged in once a user successfully logged in. Since I have a page for user and one page for the admin, how can I allow different homepages for different users once they login. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user email from `snapshot.data`.

```dart
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  //user is logged in
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    final data = snapshot.data;
    if (data?.email == "yourAdminEmail") {
      //admin
    } else {
      
    }
  }
```